# How to identify point if two gesture stroke intersect

Tags: android, android-gesture, line-intersection

I am developing a game. In my game, when two gesture lines intersect, the game will be over. How can I identify the point intersection of two gesture lines?

My code is below

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
    float temp=0,temp1=0;
    GestureOverlayView gstr;
    ArrayList<String> arr,prmt;
    View view;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gestureoverlay);


        prmt=new ArrayList<String>();
        arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        gstr=(GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.GestureView);


        gstr.setOnTouchListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE==event.getAction())
        {
        Log.i(" "+event.getX()+""+event.getY(),"state");
        if(temp!=0 && temp1!=0)
        {
            if(temp<event.getX() && temp1<event.getY())
            {
                if(event.getX()>=event.getY())
                {
                    for(float i=temp;i<=event.getX();i++)
                    {
                        if(temp1<=event.getY())
                        {
                            temp1++;
                        }
                        if(!arr.contains(i+"  "+temp1))
                        {
                            arr.add(i+"  "+temp1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for(float i=temp1;i<event.getY();i++)
                    {
                        if(temp<=event.getX())
                        {
                            temp++;
                        }
                    if(!arr.contains(temp+"  "+i))
                    {
                            arr.add(temp+"  "+i);
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "y is high",50).show(); 
                    }               }
            }
            else if(temp>event.getX() && temp1>event.getY())
            {
                if(event.getX()<=event.getY())
                {
                    for(float i=temp;i>=event.getX();i--)
                    {
                        if(temp1>=event.getY())
                        {
                            temp1--;
                        }
                        if(!arr.contains(i+"  "+temp1))
                        {
                            arr.add(i+"  "+temp1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for(float i=temp1;i>event.getY();i--)
                    {
                        if(temp>=event.getX())
                        {
                            temp--;
                        }
                        if(!arr.contains(temp+"  "+i))
                        {
                            arr.add(temp+"  "+i);
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "y is high",50).show(); 
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if(!arr.contains(event.getX()+"  "+event.getY()))
                {
                        arr.add(event.getX()+"  "+event.getY());
                    if(!arr.contains((event.getX()-1)+"  "+event.getY()))
                        arr.add((event.getX()-1)+"  "+(event.getY()));              
                    if(!arr.contains((event.getX()+1)+"  "+(event.getY())))
                        arr.add(((event.getX()+1))+"  "+(event.getY()));
                }
            }
        }

        temp=event.getX();
        temp1=event.getY();
        tv.setText("x="+event.getX()+"  "+event.getY()+"\n");
        Log.i("x and y="+event.getX()+"  "+event.getY()+" "+arr, " ");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),event.getX()+"  "+(event.getX()+1), 40).show();
        }
        if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP==event.getAction())
        {

            for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
            {
                if(!prmt.contains(arr.get(i)))
                {
                    prmt.add(arr.get(i));
                    //arr.remove(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game over",30).show();
                    Log.i("x and y=", "else");
                    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mainmenu.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            arr.clear();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "action up",50).show();   
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

But I can't get all pixel(xy coordinate). so that I could not identify intersection point every time when two gesture line cross each other.
please give me any solution or any other way for identifing common point of two drawn line

Comment: Rather than saving points of touch event you could save straight lines "drawn" by the finger between those point. This would give you one or more polylines, which you can then test for intersection. Here you have the code for calculating the intersection: http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/geometry-games/intersection-lines.html

Comment: your code work fine in case of straight line But I need to identify intersection point between curve lines. so it could not provide accurate result in case curve lines.

Comment: gesture line is rather a polyline, not a curve (the more points it has, the more it looks like a curve)

Comment: tx michal..i work like charm.

Comment: Wow, it's been almost 3 years ;-)

Comment: hahaha..its done before 3 year..yr

Comment: bt..today ur help remember..

Comment: tx again for dat day..